# Mongoose.js how to multiply field values during update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update the values in a mongodb collection using a mongoose model but i cant seem to make it work the way i want. I would like the value of a particular field to be a multiple of an updated field.

```
var id = req.user._id

Model.findById({_id: id},function(err,doc){
if(err){

console.log(err)//handle error

)//handle error

}else{
//update file

doc.field1 = req.body.formInput;
doc.field2 = {$multiply: [doc.field1, 2]};
doc.save();
};
});
```

If anyone can help please, I don't know the right way to do this and its breaking my app. Please help a brother.

Comment: Why not `doc.field2 = req.body.formInput * 2;` ?

Comment: Tryed that... it did not work

Comment: Can you console log `formInput`  to make sure we have a value ?

Comment: Yes I get the correct value Update in field1

Comment: Its a node.js app using express router and handlebars

Comment: Thanks man... if finally works. i dont know why i did not work earlier. I just tried it and it works fine with doc.field2 = req.body.formInput*2;

Comment: Take into account that req.body.formInput it's a string and not numeric, if you want to do operations like sum the result would be unexpected. I strongly recomend use parseInt(integer, 10).